# Why the messagebox show the message twice?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void tStartTime_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(CheckIfTimesExist())
            {
                bPlayPart.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                bPlayPart.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void tEndTime_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (CheckIfTimesExist())
            {
                bPlayPart.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                bPlayPart.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private bool CheckIfTimesExist()
        {
            bool timesExit;

            if (tStartTime.Text != "" && tEndTime.Text != "" && tStartTime.Text != tEndTime.Text)
            {
                timesExit = true;
            }
            else
            {
                tStartTime.Text = "";
                tEndTime.Text = "";
                MessageBox.Show("Start time and End time cannot be the same.");
                timesExit = false;
            }

            return timesExit;
        }
```

The main idea is to show a message if both cases : If both text boxes are empty or both have the same value inside. The problem is that it's showing the same message twice in a row.

Comment: I would suggest for debugging purpose, print value of `tStartTime.Text` and `tEndTime.Text` whenever you are showing message box. By this you will understand in which case message box is showing twice

Comment: When you set `tStartTime.Text = ""` etc., you cause a TextChanged event. -- Use DateTimePickers with the Time Format you prefer instead of TextBoxes. Also, you're assuming the input is valid just because is not empty or the same value. You need more than that to validate user input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You call `CheckIfTimesExist` each time Text property in `tStartTime` or `tEndTime` changes and inside of `CheckIfTimesExist` you are changing the Text property:

```cs
                // ...                
                tStartTime.Text = "";
                tEndTime.Text = "";
                // ...
```

If `tStartTime` and `tEndTime` are part of dialog window, you could call `CheckIfTimesExist` in OnFormClosing - see example in description of [CancelEventArgs.Cancel Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Condition

> If both text boxes are empty or both have the same value inside.

could be simplified - if both text boxes are empty, then the Text properties will be equal:

```
    if (tStartTime.Text != tEndTime.Text)
```